# Safe usage of window.location.href

Tags: javascript, security, correctness

I'm working on some javascript code and implemented a redirect as:

`window.location.href = window.location.href + <params>`

Let's assume that the added params are all trusted. Is there any security risk from not first validating the URL of the current page?

Comment: This depends on the context. What params? Where are they coming from? How are they trusted? More importantly, how are these parameters *escaped*?

Comment: Does `trusted` mean `valid`?

Comment: And what are you doing with the params, let's say you allow a `deleteEverything` boolean parameter, this would make untrusted GET params a security risk

Comment: Params are based on a server-side enforced whitelist of possible client-provided values. I'm most curious if validation is needed for window.location.href itself.

Comment: There is no additional risk, as *every* page needs to validate its parameters, they never are to be trusted.

Comment: So unless the parameters that you add do put some kind of trust in the url, there is no security risk in this redirection.